# trying to make "npm run dev" create 2 shell instances

Tags: javascript, bash, shell

I'm using json-server as my local server for a nuxt project and i want to automatically launch the server and then run the project on another shell instance using "npm run dev"

in the scripts tag in package.json this is what i came up with :

```
    "dev": "json-server --watch db.json --port 3004 & nuxt"
```

but this script only starts the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently)

```
npm install -g concurrently
```

`"dev": "concurrently \"json-server --watch db.json --port 3004\" \"nuxt""`

Comment: sorry for the late reply.It worked but i was getting issues with the server.I ll try to look for another way